# How to disable Twitter Analytics?

Tags: twitter, privacy

Is there a way to turn off [Analytics](https://analytics.twitter.com/about) for a Twitter account again, once enabled? [Twitter Help pages](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/using-the-tweet-activity-dashboard) didn't provide any answer.

Comment: Assuming it isn't possible, people should at least know that they're unable to revoke collecting personal data of their followers...